# Is there a way to get the ammo from a gun without picking it up?

Tags: dead-island

Ammo is hard to find and having to pick up a gun to get the ammo and then having to drop it again is very annoying.  Is there a way I can get the ammo but leave the gun on the ground?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed this as well. Sadly, it seems like there is no way to get weapon ammo any other way (besides picking up the dropped ammo boxes of enemies of course).

Comment: bah, I desperately need to find a rifle ammo mod, I have one for pistol and shotgun, but no rifle, sigh.

Answer (score 2):

The only ways to get ammo at all is by running over the dropped ammo boxes, or buying ammo from some shops (which is extremely expensive), or picking the gun up. I guess they did it so that you have at least a little bit of ammo when you pick up a gun, without making it to plentiful, I guess they just didn't realise people would do that. Your choice seems to be convenience+time vs. extra ammo.

Answer (score 0):

I've only got Xian to level 31 so far but I've found a couple of vendors later on that sell pistol, rifle and shotgun ammo (I remember seeing $500 from one vendor for pistol ammo), unconfirmed if these are part of the random stock items vendors seem to have.

There is also a Pistol Ammo Recipe that I acquired from somewhere (can't remember where off hand sorry) it's reasonable to assume that the other ammo variants will be available as well.

Comment: You are correct: eventually you will get recipes to create ammo for shotguns and rifles.

Answer (score 0):

I have all the mods for ammo and when ever I get a vendor who has bleach and metal scrap I buy as much as I can so ammo isn't an issue if you need it. Also picking up the rifles of those you kill make you a lot of money fast.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that if you use the ''duplicate weapons'' with a gun that has ammo already in it and then drop the extra guns you have duplicated you can walk over them and add extra ammo to the gun you have kept it has seemed to work great along with the convenience of getting free ammo without buying through a vendor.